# all users with four digit UID in UNIX

Tags: unix, uid

In UNIX, is there a single command that lists all users with a 4 digit uid (third field) in `etc/passwd`?

I tried

```
egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[0-9]:' /etc/passwd
```

but this is only for a single digit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{N}` to match group exactly `N` times.

So correct command would be `egrep '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[0-9]{4}:' /etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` which might be easier to read:

```
awk -F':' 'length($3)==4' /etc/passwd
```